# Networked aframe dynamic rooms not working with easy rtc

Tags: javascript, networking, three.js, aframe, aframe-networked

### Issue

Hi, I've remixed a template for networked aframe dynamic rooms using a form:

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/power-lily-pancake?path=public%2Fscene.html%3A41%3A0

For some reason whenever I add these lines of code to the `<a-scene>` tag, the entire project breaks:

```
networked-scene="
      room: audio;
      adapter: easyrtc;
      audio: true;
      video: true;
      debug: true;
      inspector=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe-inspector@master/dist/aframe-inspector.min.js"
```

I'm wondering if there is a way too add those lines of the code to the `<a-scene>` tag so it looks like this:

```
    <a-scene dynamic-room networked-scene="
      room: audio;
      adapter: easyrtc;
      audio: true;
      video: true;
      debug: true;
      inspector=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe-inspector@master/dist/aframe-inspector.min.js"
>
```

But have it so the dynamic rooms are still working. Meaning if two people are in different rooms they will not see each other, but if they are in the same  room they will be able to see each other. How can this be done?

### Links

A-frame website: https://aframe.io

Networked A-frame documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/networked-aframe

Project containing my current code: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/power-lily-pancake?path=public%2Fscene.html%3A41%3A0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

afaik the `dynamic-room` [component](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/naf-dynamic-room?path=public%2Fjs%2Fdynamic-room.component.js%3A25%3A0) is designed to attach the `networked-scene`, not update it ([since it doesn't handle updates](https://github.com/networked-aframe/networked-aframe/blob/master/src/components/networked-scene.js)). That's why the [dynamic-room example scene](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/naf-dynamic-room?path=public%2Findex.html%3A37%3A0) does only have a `dynamic-room` component, and also why the `dynamic-room` is not working with `networked-scene`.

I'd throw all the `networked-scene` attributes to the `dynamic-room` setup, but it's also possible to make the two work together pretty much like you want it:

```
<a-scene dynamic-room networked-scene>
```

One way of solving this, would be using the [`connectOnLoad` property](https://github.com/networked-aframe/networked-aframe/blob/master/src/components/networked-scene.js#L20) of the `networked-scene` - let the `dynamic-room` change the room, and then decide when to connect.

Since `networked-scene` checks the `connectOnLoad` in [init](https://github.com/networked-aframe/networked-aframe/blob/master/src/components/networked-scene.js#L16) - it will always use the default value. We need to make sure the default is `false` instead of `true`.

---

So two things need to be made:

1. change `networked-scene` defaults before the scene is initialized:

   ```
   <script>
     // This is hacky, another way would be copying the component and make it react to updates
     AFRAME.components["networked-scene"].schema.connectOnLoad.default = false;
   </script>

   <a-scene dynamic-room networked-scene>
   ```
2. emit `connect` when the room id is set:

   ```
   // set the room id
   el.setAttribute("networked-scene", "room", roomID);    

   // notify `networked-scene` that you're ready to connect 
   el.emit("connect", null, false);
   ```

Check it out in [this glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stack-69138587?path=public%2Fscene.html%3A17%3A12)

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. The code works perfectly! I do have one issue with regarding changing from networked-scene to dynamic-room. I've posted another question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69306679/networked-a-frame-issue-with-dynamic-room-and-video. If you wanted to check out the issue, it would mean a lot to me.  If not, of course that's perfectly fine as well. Thank you again for your answer!