# Networked A-frame issue with dynamic-room and video

Tags: javascript, networking, three.js, aframe, aframe-networked

I am creating a project using **A-frame** (https://aframe.io) and the **networked A-frame component** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/networked-aframe)

(project at: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/networkedtest?path=public%2Fscene.html%3A44%3A0)

and I've run into an issue with the video feed. Currently in my project, video feed is working perfectly fine, but whenever I switch this line of code **in scene.html on line 202:**

```
   <a-scene moving-sun vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;" physics networked-scene="
      room: audio;
      adapter: easyrtc;
      audio: true;
      video: true;
      debug: true;
      inspector=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe-inspector@master/dist/aframe-inspector.min.js">
```

With this code:

```
<a-scene moving-sun vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;" physics dynamic-room="
  room: audio;
  adapter: easyrtc;
  audio: true;
  video: true;
  debug: true;
  inspector=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe-inspector@master/dist/aframe-inspector.min.js">
```

If I test my code by pulling up two tabs, where the video feed should be there is just a blank white plane. I'm not sure why, but whenever I exchange the part of the line  `networked-scene=""`
with  `dynamic-room=""` the video feed stops working and when you join on another tab, all you see is a white screen where the video feed should be.

I'm not sure why this is happening since all I'm changing is `networked-scene` for `dynamic-room`. I've tried fixing this error by modifying some code but still can't find an answer to this issue. I have a feeling that the issue is somewhere in `public/js/dynamic-room.component.js` but I may be mistaken.

If you know how to solve this problem, help would be very much appreciated.

Link to my project: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/networkedtest?path=public%2Fscene.html%3A44%3A0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.

I assume you want to use dynamic-room to load a custom room name from the URL. (That is all it is for. If that is not what you want, then dynamic-room is not what you are looking for.)

The dynamic room example reads the URL, then creates the "networked-scene" component for you and attaches it to your  tag.

It is an old example, written before video support, so it does not check for `video: true`:

```js
var isMultiuser = params.hasOwnProperty('room');
var webrtc = params.hasOwnProperty('webrtc');
var adapter = webrtc ? 'easyrtc' : 'wseasyrtc';
var voice = params.hasOwnProperty('voice');

var networkedComp = {
    room: params.room,
    adapter: adapter,
    audio: voice //<--Only setting the audio property here
};
console.info('Init networked-aframe with settings:', networkedComp);
el.setAttribute('networked-scene', networkedComp);
```

I recommend copying your parameters into `dynamic-room.component.js` (at line 18).

Only the room name will load from the URL. (And will default to 'audio' if not specified, just like your networked-scene parameter.)

```js
var roomNameFromURL = params.hasOwnProperty('room');
//We won't check for these:
//var webrtc = params.hasOwnProperty('webrtc');
//var adapter = webrtc ? 'easyrtc' : 'wseasyrtc';
//var voice = params.hasOwnProperty('voice');

var networkedComp = {
    //if there is no name in the URL, default to 'audio',
    //  like your networked-scene
    room: roomNameFromURL ? params.room : 'audio',
    adapter: 'easyrtc',
    audio: true,
    video: true,
    debug: true
};
console.info('Init networked-aframe with settings:', networkedComp);
el.setAttribute('networked-scene', networkedComp);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69138587/networked-aframe-dynamic-rooms-not-working-with-easy-rtc).

Your `dynamic-room` only sets the room id, and emits `connect` so the `networked-scene` attempts to connect to the server:

```
// public/js/dynamic-room.component.js

// Setup networked-scene
var networkedComp = {
  room: params.room
};
// set the room
el.setAttribute("networked-scene", networkedComp);    
// emit connect
el.emit("connect", null, false);
```

in this case, its not an alternative to `networked-scene`, they work together. If you disable auto-connect before the scene:

```
<script>
AFRAME.components["networked-scene"].schema.connectOnLoad.default = false;
</script>
<a-scene dynamic-room networked-scene>
```

The video shows up as expected ([glitch here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/zippy-wooded-lilac?path=public%2Fscene.html%3A202%3A0))

---

If you want the `dynamic-room` to do all setup which is in the `networked-scene`, then Michaels answer is also correct.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: btw check out the console warnings / errors, there are multiple things to clean up, which sooner or later may lead to serious bugs

Comment: All right, thanks for the tip!